# How to count double vowels in python?

Tags: python

I try to count the vowel plus special consonants. The value of the vowel is -1 and the consonant is 2. But when I input multiple same vowels or consonants, it only counts one. Here the code

```
def countVowels(user_input, vowel_list):
    vowels = 0
    for i in vowel_list:
        if i in user_input:
            vowels -= 1
    return(vowels)

def countConsonantsSpecial(user_input, count_ConsonantsSpecial):
    special_consonants = 0
    for i in count_ConsonantsSpecial:
        if i in user_input:
            special_consonants += 2
    return special_consonants

def main():
   user_input = input("Enter a string of vowels and consonants:").lower()
   vowel_list = set(['a','e','i','o','u']) #value -1
   v = int(countVowels(user_input, vowel_list))

   count_Consonants = set(['f', 'q', 'v', 'x', 'z']) #value 2
   cs = int(countConsonants(user_input, count_Consonants))

   total_count = print(v + cs)
main()
```

I tried an example :

```
>>>Enter a string of vowels and consonants:aauzziiu
1
```

The result should be -2

Comment: Why should the result be -2?

Comment: Because it work like this : (-1 -1 -1) + 2 + 2 + (-1 -1 -1)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Change the following lines:

```
if i in user_input:
    special_consonants += 2
```

to

```
special_consonants += 2 * user_input.count(i)
```

and the following lines:

```
if i in user_input:
    vowels -= 1
```

to

```
vowels -= user_input.count(i)
```

That being said, the result for your sample input won't change as there are 2 consonants (+4) and 4 vowels (-4).

Comment: Ohh I see, thank you! it solved

Answer (score 2):

You specifically count only one of each letter:

```
def countVowels(user_input, vowel_list):
    vowels = 0
    for i in vowel_list:
        if i in user_input:
            vowels -= 1
    return(vowels)
```

Your `if` merely checks to see whether there is *any* of that vowel in the input; it doesn't count how many there are.  You have two "minimal" ways to fix this:

(1) Switch the logic; iterate through the input, and see whether each letter is a vowel.

```
def countVowels(user_input, vowel_list):
    vowels = 0
    for i in user_input:
        if i in vowel_list:
            vowels -= 1
    return(vowels)
```

(2) Count the vowels instead of checking for mere existence:

```
def countVowels(user_input, vowel_list):
    vowels = 0
    for i in vowel_list:
        vowels -= user_input.count(i)
    return(vowels)
```

Whichever method you choose, you'll need to alter the consonant scoring the same way.